# jQuery variable undefined when storing number from .attr('href')

Tags: jquery, variables, attr

I'm trying to get the number from this link

```
   <div id="section-tabs-header">
   <a id="section-tabs-header-subtitle" class="ellipsis" href="/courses/123456">Math 101</a>
```

and store it in a variable

```
var courseID = $("div#section-tabs-header a#section-tabs-header-subtitle").attr("href").match(/\d+/);
console.log(courseID);
```

but the variable is "undefined."

http://jsbin.com/ukogam/2/edit

Is it because what jQuery is finding is html rather than the plain text of the number? How do I get just the number?

Comment: `$("#main a").attr("href","/courses/" + courseID);`  and include jquery: http://jsbin.com/eyoxir/1/

Comment: Your code works perfectly ok:  http://jsfiddle.net/JqfH4/.  But might I suggest you shorten your query to `$('#section-tabs-header-subtitle').attr('href').match(/\d+/)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't see anything about the variable being undefined. I got that $ was undefined so I included jQuery. Then I got that href wasn't a function so I modified some code that was after the code you mentioned to this: `$("#main a").attr("href","/courses/" + courseID);`

I think this is working how you expect? http://jsbin.com/egevok/1/edit

Answer (score 1):

I modified it, have a look http://jsbin.com/iculoq/2/edit.

```
var courseID = $("#section-tabs-header-subtitle").attr("href").split('/')[2];

$("#main a").attr('href', "/courses/" + courseID);
```

Comment: please feel free to comment on downvote, this answer is better in sense of an url can contains number in subfolder too, but i'd use instead: `.split('/').pop()`

Comment: @roasted, I've removed my downvote, but I do feel if there's nothing wrong with the OP's code (i.e., we can't replicate his results), then it's patently ridiculous to provide a "correct" answer that "fixes" his unbroken code. The OP's may not be the best code, but the problem was his failure to include jQuery, not an inherent problem with the code.

Comment: @DerekHenderson your comment is really appreciated! If you had commented your downvote, i'd have nothing to say agaisnt it, makes sense

Answer (score 1):

```
var href = $("#section-tabs-header-subtitle")
  .attr("href");
console.log(href);
var courseID =  href.match(/\d+/);
console.log(courseID);

$("#main a").attr("href","/courses/" + courseID);
```